# Entering multiple entries in SQL where the count increases by one

Tags: mysql, php

I do apologize for the uninspired title, I'm not sure how best to put it.

Another person helped me massively in [another question I posted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116958/storing-undetermined-amounts-of-user-information-mysql/116969?noredirect=1#comment214730_116969) regarding the structuring of data.

The solution has left me with another bit of a brain ache. I will paste some of that users response to me as it reflects what I currently have, I do apologize if that is poor etiquette.

Basically I'm allowing users to store a certain amount of text information each day, for example, 7 entries daily. Entries referenced as *things*.

The current structure works as follows (`UID` is Users ID + Date):

```
Things
PK          PK
UID         thing_id  thing
71420150404 0000001   First thing
71420150404 0000002   Second thing
```

The user that helped me before came up with the following way to enter data:

```
INSERT INTO test.Things(UID,thing_id,thing,thing_date)
SELECT
    :uid,
    MAX(IFNULL(thing_id,0))+1,
    :thing1,
    NOW()
FROM test.Things
WHERE UID=:uid
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE thing=:thing1,thing_date=NOW();
```

This works perfectly, however the problem is only one entry can be added at a time. A workaround I've found is to take all the entries (*things*) as an array in my PHP and execute the SQL statement over and over for each entry. This seems highly inefficient.

Though I have been getting the basics of SQL through online courses I haven't been able to work out how to a better solution to this through SQL itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'd suggested on comments, this is a trigger in action `BEFORE INSERT` to autogenerate a `thing_id` with the `UID` given.

### TRIGGER:

```
USE `test`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test.Things_BEFORE_INSERT$$
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`Things_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Things` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.thing_id=IFNULL((SELECT MAX(thing_id)+1 FROM test.Things WHERE UID=NEW.UID),1); -- If NULL set it to 1 as first thing_id for this UID
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*Note: Change the database and table to yours.*

### Test:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.Things;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> USE `test`;
Database changed
mysql> 
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> 
mysql> DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS test.Things_BEFORE_INSERT$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE `test`$$
Database changed
mysql> CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`Things_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `Things` FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> SET NEW.thing_id=IFNULL((SELECT MAX(thing_id)+1 FROM test.Things WHERE UID=NEW.UID),1); -- If NULL set it to 1 as first thing_id for this UID
    -> END
    -> $$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.12 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql> 
mysql> SET @UID='71420150404',@thing1='First Thing.',@thing2='Second Thing.',@thing3='Third Thing.';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> INSERT INTO test.Things(UID,thing) 
    -> VALUES (@UID,@thing1),(@UID,@thing2),(@UID,@thing3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 1 warning (0.09 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.Things;
+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+
| UID         | thing_id | thing         | thing_date |
+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+
| 71420150404 |  0000001 | First Thing.  | NULL       |
| 71420150404 |  0000002 | Second Thing. | NULL       |
| 71420150404 |  0000003 | Third Thing.  | NULL       |
+-------------+----------+---------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```